# Convert an existing method to a decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I am working on a legacy python 2.7 application

Current Implementation

```
# First decorator
def print_sep_args(param, color):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print_color('=' * 60 + 'Checking for {0}'.format(param) + '=' * 60, color)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@print_sep_args('acc', 'cyan')
def check_usedacc():
    print('Checking for account : {0}'.format(acc))
    ad = subprocess.check_output(["python", "abc.py", 123])
    consolidate_red(ad)
```

Can i convert this method to a decorator?

```
# Method to be implemented
def consolidate_red(output):
    func_work_on(output)
```

I would need to insert this functionality into many existing functions.

Comment: As an aside, running Python as a subprocess of itself is almost always a bad idea. Refactor `abc.py` so you can `import` it into the calling script; use `multiprocessing` if you need it to run in a separate process.

Comment: It's not clear how these functions fit together or what's missing. Please [edit] to clarify which part you need help with. What is the role of `func_work_on` and what does the current implementation of `consolidate_red` look like? What's the purpose of these functions?